# Keeping The Command Window Open For Errors During Process

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, command-line, process

Alright, the current code below is how I'm calling a process. The process is not running correctly (causing an error) and thus quickly opening the command line and closing it before I get a chance to see what the error is. More than likely its with a couple arguments that I'm using.

```
   Using psinfo As New Process
      psinfo.StartInfo.FileName = Arg1
      psinfo.StartInfo.Arguments = Arg2 + Arg3 + Arg4 + Arg5
      psinfo.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
      psinfo.Start()
      psinfo.WaitForExit()
   End Using
```

Can I keep this window or pause or anything so I can see what the errors are?

Is there a common practice I should be using to find errors during a process?

Comment: Create a .cmd file with two lines.  First one is `c:\foo\bar\app.exe %1 %2 %3 %4`, second line is `pause`.

Comment: It might be easier to just redirect StandardError (or StandardOut) and parse the output in the case of an error.